# Setting-up WinRM HTTPS on Azure VMs

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I was guided to install "WinRM on a Windows VM" quick start template so I can use Azure File Copy deployment task on visual studio build automation, in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/31/dev-test-in-azure-and-deploy-to-production-on-premises.aspx

I am trying to deploy [the template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-winrm-windows-vm) but I am confused. The required parameters involve VM machine name, size etc. I was thinking I could deploy this template on an existing VM, not on a new one.

Is this template only for new VMs?

Igor.

Comment: The template you are trying to use is an azure resource manager template, that creates a new vm and sets up WinRM. In your case you just need to enable WinRM on your existing vm.

Comment: Thank you @melsaqqa It seems this template is useless for me. Configuring WinRM is being a problematic thing so far. I don't know if I am missing something on visual studio online deployment task configuration or something wrong with WinRM. How can I make sure WinRM is OK for this deployment so I can focus on visual studio configuration? Is there any powershell test I can perform from my PC to check requirements? Thank you.

Comment: Website https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-winrm-windows-vm mentions "This template installs a certificate from Azure Key Vault on a Virtual Machine and opens up WinRM HTTP and HTTPS listeners. You need to have a certificate uploaded to Azure Key Vault for this template to work."